# Jest coverage test does not include 'rewired' files

Tags: npm, jestjs, babel-jest, rewire

I am including my non-exported function (let's say A) to the Jest unit tests with the 'rewire' function. When I run the coverage test, the A function is not included to the coverage test. Is there any way to include rewired files to the coverage test?

Is there any configurations which should be provided to the babel.config.json?

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": ["babel-plugin-rewire"]
}
```